# Error message: "Electron Framework: file too short" on USB stick

Tags: macos, electron

In my company, we have a problem with software that we are planning to distribute using USB sticks. We tested on various systems and everything worked fine, so we gave it to production. After production we tested the sticks again just to make sure, and none of the sticks worked on macOS.
Also, none of the old test sticks (before production) are working anymore, but also only on macOS.

We keep getting this error message. Can somebody help?

```
Process:               im.puls Demo App [829]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/im.puls Demo App
Identifier:            com.electron.im.puls-demo-app
Version:               1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           im.puls Demo App [829]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-09-14 12:42:43.224 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        68179AF5-C5A1-96FF-0096-4C1D0024A6D9


Time Awake Since Boot: 4000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
  Referenced from: /Volumes/VOLUME/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/im.puls Demo App
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Volumes/IMPULS DEMO/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework: file too short
    /Volumes/IMPULS DEMO/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework: stat() failed with errno=1

Binary Images:
       0x101fb7000 -        0x101fb7ff7 +com.electron.im.puls-demo-app (1.0.0 - 1.0.0) <F8DFE287-C6B4-3716-B3B3-CDF539205B40> /Volumes/VOLUME/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/im.puls Demo App
       0x10ff40000 -        0x10ff8aacf  dyld (551.4) <8A72DE9C-A136-3506-AA02-4BA2B82DCAF3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff4ee9f000 -     0x7fff4efa3ffb  com.apple.Bluetooth (6.0.7 - 6.0.7f10) <557F26F9-C7A0-34EA-A905-22E243BF6B48> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00DA.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.18.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500,11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Mass Storage
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

I think this part of the message might be most important:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
  Referenced from: /Volumes/VOLUME/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/im.puls Demo App
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Volumes/IMPULS DEMO/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework: file too short
    /Volumes/IMPULS DEMO/im.puls Demo starten.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: Hi, if you packed your app in `tar.gz` format could you try packing it in `zip` format instead and say whether it resolves the problem?

Comment: Thx for your answer. The problem is resolved already. I will close the question

Comment: @micha_nerd what did you do to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: @PaulRey the problem resulted from the USB-stick-producer. They were unable to oack the usb-sticks properly. We talked with them and told them, that we specifically wanted the sticks to also work on mac and with this information they made it work.

Comment: Any idea what the issue could have been specifically?